# what is the correct HTC Vive barrel distortion radius function?

Tags: processing, htc-vive

I have a HTC Vive and am interested in creating processing sketches to use in VR. 
I found a great library that does exactly that:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Your-HTC-Vive-With-Processing/
It has been great so far but I found have found it be quite limited with a lot less code than I would have expected. 
What I want to do in the HTC Vive is to use a barrel distortion so I can fix the pincushion distortion vr devices have. Here is a link to what I mean:
http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/vr/node208.html
And a solution to lens distortion: 
https://smus.com/vr-lens-distortion/

I have found another library that uses the barrel distortion - Camera3D
https://ixora.io/projects/camera-3D/barrel-distortion/
https://github.com/hx2A/Camera3D/blob/master/src/camera3D/generators/BarrelDistortionGenerator.java
However this can only be used for the Oculus Rift and Google cardboard, and both Camera3D and Vive.p5 librarys wont work together as they both need to control the camera.

So from what I have researched this problem has not been done on the HTC Vive yet in processing. 
I am not an expert in processing so any help or direction on how to implement this barrel distortion would be great!

I also found the display code for the HTC Vive, which may help: 
https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Vive/blob/master/displays/HTC_Vive.json

I have also posted this information on the processing forum: https://discourse.processing.org/t/using-processing-for-the-htc-vive/5764

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/using-processing-for-the-htc-vive/5764